# Make flag visible when the the plot is clicked to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Ok, let me explain :)

I have right now one chart with 4 lines, when I open the chart only one of it is by default visible.

Each of the lines has a flag attached to it, the problem is: when the line is not visible the flag appears at the bottom of the chart.

[image: my chart]

I found the command to make the flag visible or not, but the problem is, unlike the lines when I click the line to appear, the flag does not appear with it.

Is there any way to make them appear together? Like then I click to show the 'Camara 4' line the flag appear together. And when I click to make the line invisible the flag turn invisible too.

Is there any function/command for it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bBQKv/

Make use of the show and hide events to trigger the show and hide methods for the flag series.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            show: function(event) {
                if (this.options.type != 'flags') {
                    series = this.chart.get(this.options.id + 'Flags');
                    series.show();
                }
            },
            hide: function(event) {
                if (this.options.type != 'flags') {
                    series = this.chart.get(this.options.id + 'Flags');
                    series.hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```